# Understanding chain rule in a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, chain-rule

I am currently self-studying differential geometry from O'Neill's *Semi-Riemannian Geometry With Applications to Relativity*. In the proof of Lemma 6 (page 40 of my edition, first Lemma in the section regarding contractions in chapter 2), he uses that, if $\xi = (x^1,\dots,x^n),\ \eta = (y^1, \dots, y^n)$ are two overlapping coordinate systems on a manifold $M$, then

$$
\sum_m \frac{\partial y^m}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^m} = \delta^i_j
$$

Where $m$ ranges from 1 to the dimension of the manifold. I do understand that the notation is thought to be reminiscent of the case where we simply have derivatives in $\mathbb{R}^n$, in which case the result is trivial, but following the definitions given in said book about derivatives in a manifold, shouldn't this last sum be equal to

$$ 
\sum_m \left(\frac{\partial \left(y^m\circ\xi^{-1}\right)}{\partial u^j}\circ\xi\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\partial \left(x^i\circ\eta^{-1}\right)}{\partial u^m}\circ\eta\right)
$$

Where (following the conventions of the book), $u^1,\dots, u^n$ are the *natural coordinate functions* of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If this is the case, I wonder how one should go about proving that this last sum is actually equal to $\delta^i_j$.

Comment: You are looking at the functions $\eta\circ\xi^{-1}$ and $\xi\circ\eta^{-1}$. You have $y=\eta\circ\xi^{-1}(x)$ and $x=\xi\circ\eta^{-1}(y)$. The statement is the chain rule for $(\eta\circ\xi^{-1})\circ(\eta\circ\xi^{-1}){}^{-1}$. There is really no mapping of manifolds here, just a mapping and its inverse on open sets of Euclidean space. You've introduced too much extraneous stuff.